# Storyboard placement incorrect

Tags: ios, layout, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have a UIScrollView placed inside a UIScrollView container.  While the placement of the sub-view appears correct in the Storyboard, it is off when I run the app (both on the simulator and an external device).  In order for the view to appear properly, I have to place it oddly in the storyboard as follows:

Layout appears correct in storyboard but incorrect in app:
[image: Incorrect placement of sub-UIScrollView]

Layout appears incorrect in storyboard but correct in app:
[image]

To enable vertical scrolling in the parent UIScrollView, I turned off Auto Layout, and for the ViewController, I set size to 'freeform"

Does anyone have advice for how to layout my views to appear correct both in the storyboard and in the app?

Comment: Try setting the frame of the scrollview in viewDidLoad

Comment: I added this line to viewDidLoad:     [pageScroller addSubview:imageScroller];  Unfortunately, it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Another idea: check if the content of the inner scrollview is inset correctly.

Comment: thanks for your help – all the insets are set to 0, so I don't think this is the issue.